# Having error attempting to use RTDB in Expo managed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm attempting to use firebase realtime database on my app.  I first authenticate and then I need to use the RTDB.  Here is my attempt.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

import getEnvVars from '../environment';
const ENV = getEnvVars();

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ENV.firebase.API_KEY,
  authDomain: ENV.firebase.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: ENV.firebase.DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: ENV.firebase.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: ENV.firebase.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: ENV.firebase.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: ENV.firebase.APP_ID
};



initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getDatabase();
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: (0, _database.getDatabase) is not a function. (In '(0, _database.getDatabase)()', '(0, _database.getDatabase)' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the old, namespaced syntax of SDK versions 8 and lower, with the new, modular syntax of SDK versions 9 and above.

To get the database in v9, you call `getDatabase()` as a top-level function:

```
export const db = getDatabase();
```

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation ready when going through this, as it has code samples for both the old and new syntax so you can easily compare. For this specific call, see the documentation on [getting a database reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#get_a_database_reference).

Comment: I should have noted I tried that also... sorry.   It says database.getDatabase is undefined.  '(0,_database.getDatabase)'is undefined.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I recommend updating your question with the one approach that should have worked, instead of everything you tried, and the error you get. This error message though `_database.getDatabase` seems to suggest you are still calling `getDatabase` on something, instead of as a top-level function.

Comment: I think I found my error I'm using "firebase": "7.9.0"

Comment: In that case, click on the `Web version 8 (namespaced)` tab in the documentation to get a code sample that is relevant for you.